# How can I go about querying a database for non-similar, but almost matching items

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, matching

How can I go about querying a database for items that are not only exactly similar to a sample, but also those that are almost similar? Almost as search engines work, but only for a small project, preferably in Java. For example:

```
String sample = "Sample";
```

I would like to retrieve all the following whenever I query `sample`:

```
String exactMatch = "Sample";
String nonExactMatch = "S   amp   le";
String nonExactMatch_2 = "ampls";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define what *similar* means in terms that your database can understand.

Some possibilities include Levenshtein distance, for example.

In your example, *sample* matches...

..."Sample", if you search without case sensitivity.

..."S   amp   le", if you remove a set of ignored characters (here space only) from both the query string and the target string. You can store the new value in the database:

```
   ActualValue      SearchFor
   John Q. Smith    johnqsmith%
```

When someone searches for "John Q. Smith, Esq." you can boil it down to johnqsmithesq and run

```
   WHERE 'johnqsmithesq' LIKE SearchFor
```

"ampls" is more tricky. Why is it that 'ampls' is matched by 'sample'? A common substring? A number of shared letters? Does their order count (i.e. are anagrams valid)? Many approaches are possible, but **it is you who must decide**. You might use Levenshtein distance, or maybe store a string such as "100020010003..." where every digit encodes the number of letters you have, up to 9 (so 3 C's and 2 B's but no A's would give "023...") and then run the Levenshtein distance between this syndrome and the one from each term in the DB:

```
 ActualValue    Search1     Rhymes  abcdefghij_Contains  anagramOf
 John Q. Smith  johnqsmith% ith     0000000211011...     hhijmnoqst
```

...and so on.

One approach is to ask oneself, *how must I transform both searched value and value searched for, so that they match?*, and then proceed and implement that in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use match_against in myisam full text indexes columns.